# Looking at previous item in handlebars loop MeteorJS

Tags: mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a template in which I want to generate some HTML only if the current item has some different fields from the previous item.

```
{{#each item}}
  // if previous item.ar == current item.var, do X
  // else, do Y
{{/each}
```

How can I access the previous item?

Comment: I think this is something to do with helpers since you are handling the sorting there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transform your data via your helper. Here's an example using kittens... because everyone loves kittens right?

```js
Template.feline.helpers({
  kittens: function() {
    // fetch some kittens
    var kittens = Cats.find({_id: {$in: this.kittens}}).fetch();

    // keep track of the last kitten
    previousKitten = {};

    return _.map(kittens, function(kitten) {
      // add an isAwesome property based on the previous kitten
      if (previousKitten.eyeColor === kitten.eyeColor)
        kitten.isAwesome = true;

      previousKitten = kitten
      return kitten;
    });
  }
});
```

Now inside of the `{{#each kittens}}` iterator, you can test for the existence of `isAwesome`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible with Handlebars.
However, you can access the current index or key in the each loop like this: 
    //for arrays
    {{#each array}}
      {{@index}}
    {{/each}}

```
//for objects
{{#each object}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

You could then create an helper to test if the two values are equal:

```
{{#each array}}
  {{#if isEqual @index}}
{{/each}}

//helper
Template.yourTemplate.helper = {
  isEqual: function(index){
    (yourData[index].var === yourData[index-1].var) ? true : false;
  }
};
```

Edit: this is not available in Spacebars for the moment!

Comment: `@index` isn't currently available in spacebars, but it will be in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and solved it with some helper functions. The idea was to create some helpers to do math and comparisons, and then a helper to lookup a specific entry in an object.

Math:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper({
    add: function () {
        'use strict';
        var total = 0;
        var i = arguments.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (typeof arguments[i] === 'number') {
                total += arguments[i];
            }
        }

        return total;
    },
    subtract: function () {
        'use strict';
        var total = 0;
        var i = arguments.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (typeof arguments[i] === 'number') {
                total -= arguments[i];
            }
        }

        return total;
    },
    multiply: function () {
        'use strict';
        var total = 0;
        var i = arguments.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (typeof arguments[i] === 'number') {
                total *= arguments[i];
            }
        }

        return total;
    },
    divide: function () {
        'use strict';
        var total = 0;
        var i = arguments.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (typeof arguments[i] === 'number') {
                total /= arguments[i];
            }
        }

        return total;
    },
    modulus: function () {
        'use strict';
        var total = 0;
        var i = arguments.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (typeof arguments[i] === 'number') {
                total %= arguments[i];
            }
        }

        return total;
    },
});
```

Comparison:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper({
    eq: function (v1, v2) {
        'use strict';

        return v1 === v2;
    },
    ne: function (v1, v2) {
        'use strict';

        return v1 !== v2;
    },
    lt: function (v1, v2) {
        'use strict';

        return v1 < v2;
    },
    gt: function (v1, v2) {
        'use strict';

        return v1 > v2;
    },
    lte: function (v1, v2) {
        'use strict';

        return v1 <= v2;
    },
    gte: function (v1, v2) {
        'use strict';

        return v1 >= v2;
    },
    and: function (v1, v2) {
        'use strict';

        return v1 && v2;
    },
    or: function (v1, v2) {
        'use strict';

        return v1 || v2;
    },
});
```

And the function to lookup a specific item in an object:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getValueByPath', function () {
    'use strict';
    var options = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    var result = options.data.root;

    // the options object is the last in the list of arguments; don't loop over it
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        try {
            result = result[arguments[i]];
        } catch (err) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return result;
});
```

Then it can be used like:

```
{{#each item}}
  {{#if (eq (getValueByPath "items" (add @index 1) "property") property)}}
    // do something
  {{else}}
    // do something else
  {{/if}}
{{/each}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably the only person still using handlebars, but here is what worked for me.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper({
    ifSameAsPrevious: function (array, index, key, options) {
        return (array[index-1] && (array[index][key] === array[index-1][key])) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

And here is the usage using your example:

```
{{#items}}
    {{#ifSameAsPrevious ../items @index "var"}}
        // do something if true
    {{else}}
        // do something if false
    {{/ifSameAsPrevious}}
{{/items}
```

Comment: Bonus Note: in my case I only wanted to do something if the values didn't match, so my ternary operator looked like this `return (array[index-1] && (array[index][key] === array[index-1][key])) ? options.inverse(this) : options.fn(this);` and then I would just use the if with no else.